# composing different types of make_pack_indices

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, recursion

Suppose:

- `make_pack_indices<START, END>::type` is the type `pack_indices<START, START+1, START+2, ..., END-1>`
- `make_reverse_indices<std::size_t SIZE>::type` is the type `pack_indices<SIZE-1, SIZE-2, ..., 2, 1, 0>`
- `make_rotated_indices<SIZE, SHIFT>::type` is the type `pack_indices<SHIFT, SHIFT+1, ..., SIZE-1, 0, 1, 2, ..., SHIFT-1>`
- `make_alternating_indices<SIZE, START, INTERVAL>::type` is the type `pack_indices<START, START + INTERVAL, START + 2 * INTERVAL, ...>` until the largest index less than `START` is reached.

How do I carry out a combination of these forms of make_indices through some sort of composition like

```
compose<A, C, B, A..., D>::type,
```

where `A,B,C,D` are types (functors or whatever) representing the above four `make_indices` types?  So for example,

```
A = make_pack_indices<1,4>
B = make_reverse_indices<5>
C = make_rotated_indices<5,2>
```

Then

```
compose<B,C,A>::type
```

would be

```
pack_indices<4,3,2,1,0> -> pack_indices<2,1,0,4,3> -> pack_indices<1,0,4>
```

A simpler example is that

```
compose <make_rotated_indices<10,2>, make_rotated_indices<10,4>>::type
```

would be

```
make_rotated_indices<10,6>::type.
```

Here is an application.  Suppose we have the argument pack

```
('a', 3.14 , 5, "home", '!', 4.5, "car", 20, 0.5, 'b')
```

We can reverse this using my make_reverse_indices<10>, and we can rotate it to the left by 3 using make_rotated_indices<10,3>. But suppose I want to reverse the pack followed by rotating to the left by 3.  Instead of manually doing one followed by the other, I want to define a compose struct that will take make_reverse_indices<10> and make_rotated_indices<10,3> as parameters and give the desired result all in one go, which would be

```
("car", 4.5, '!', "home", 5, 3.14, 'a', 'b', 0.5, 20)
```

I think (in the above example) make_reverse_indices<10> and make_rotated_indices<10,3> themselves would need to be converted to something else. make_reverse_indices<10> gives 9,8,7,...,1,0. So make_rotated_indices<10,3> (instead of giving 3,4,5,...9,0,1,2) needs to be turned into another function that accepts the parameter pack 9,8,7,...,1,0 and then carry out the effect of make_rotated_indices<10,3>, thereby giving 6,5,4,...0,9,8,7.  Another idea I'm working on:  define a helper function to extract the indices from rotated_indices<10,3>::type, turn that into a parameter pack and then apply make_rotated_indices<10,3> on that parameter pack.

Here is the code I already have, in case anyone needs it for testing (the structs themselves have already been tested thoroughly):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template<std::size_t...>
struct pack_indices
{
    using type = pack_indices;
};

constexpr int positiveModulo(int i, int n)
{
    return (i % n + n) % n;
}

template<std::size_t START, std::size_t END, std::size_t... INDICES>
struct make_indices : make_indices<START + 1, END, INDICES..., START>
{};

template<std::size_t END, std::size_t... INDICES>
struct make_indices<END, END, INDICES...> : pack_indices <INDICES...>
{};


template<std::size_t SIZE, std::size_t... INDICES>
struct make_reverse_indices : make_reverse_indices<SIZE - 1, INDICES..., SIZE - 1>
{};

template<std::size_t... INDICES>
struct make_reverse_indices<0, INDICES...> : pack_indices<INDICES...>
{};


template<std::size_t SIZE, std::size_t SHIFT, std::size_t SHIFT_, std::size_t... INDICES> 
struct make_rotated_indices_helper
    : make_rotated_indices_helper<SIZE, SHIFT, SHIFT_ + 1, INDICES..., positiveModulo(SHIFT + SHIFT_, SIZE)>
{};

template<std::size_t SIZE, std::size_t SHIFT, std::size_t...INDICES>
struct make_rotated_indices_helper<SIZE, SHIFT, SIZE, INDICES...> : pack_indices<INDICES...>
{};

template<std::size_t SIZE, std::size_t SHIFT, std::size_t... INDICES>
struct make_rotated_indices
{
    using type = make_rotated_indices_helper<SIZE, SHIFT, 0, INDICES...>;
};

template<std::size_t SIZE, std::size_t START, std::size_t INTERVAL, std::size_t NUM_LEFT, std::size_t... INDICES>
    struct make_alternating_indices_helper
        : make_alternating_indices_helper<SIZE, START + INTERVAL, INTERVAL, NUM_LEFT - 1, INDICES..., positiveModulo(START, SIZE)>
    {};

template<std::size_t SIZE, std::size_t START, std::size_t INTERVAL, std::size_t... INDICES>
struct make_alternating_indices_helper<SIZE, START, INTERVAL, 0, INDICES...>
    : pack_indices<INDICES...>
{};

template<std::size_t SIZE, std::size_t START, std::size_t INTERVAL, std::size_t... INDICES>
struct make_alternating_indices 
{
    using type = make_alternating_indices_helper<SIZE, START, INTERVAL, (SIZE - 1) / INTERVAL + 1>;
};

// Testing
namespace Pack 
{
    template<typename LAST>
    void print(LAST && last)
    {
        std::cout << std::forward<LAST>(last) << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename FIRST, typename... REST>
    void print(FIRST && first, REST&&... rest)
    {
        std::cout << std::forward<FIRST>(first) << ", ";
        print<REST...>(std::forward<REST>(rest)...);
    }
}

template<typename TUPLE, std::size_t... INDICES>
void showValuesHelper(TUPLE&& tuple,
                                const pack_indices<INDICES...>&)
{
    Pack::print(std::get<INDICES>(std::forward<TUPLE>(tuple))...);
}

template<std::size_t START, std::size_t END, typename... TYPES>
void showMiddleValues(TYPES && ...types)
{
    const auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<TYPES>(types)...);
    const typename make_indices<START, END>::type indices;
    showValuesHelper (tuple, indices);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "original argument pack: ";
    Pack::print('a', 3.14, 5, "home", '!', 4.5, "car", 20, 0.5, 'b');

    std::cout << "showMiddleValues<2,7> = ";
    showMiddleValues<2, 7>('a', 3.14, 5, "home", '!', 4.5, "car", 20, 0.5, 'b'); // 5, home, !, 4.5, car
}
```

Comment: This post is unreadable. I made an edit to fix it, but you overwrote it. Take a look in the revision history to see how to format code.

Comment: I think it is fixed now.

Comment: So...you're looking for a way to concatenate multiple index sequences into a single sequence? Something like `template <typename, typename> struct concat; template <std::size_t..I, std::size_t...J> struct concat<pack_indices<I...>, pack_indices<J...>> { using type = pack_indices<I..., J...>; };` ?

Comment: Your `compose` example does not seem to concatenate the sequences. I really can't say what it does. If you consider your templates as functions composition would be applying the result of one function to another function. This is simply not possible with your templates since the accepted types and the return types do not match.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ah, that's supposed to be a list. So OP wants a meta-function taking N nullary meta-functions returning a list with the results of those functions. I don't see the purpose of such a thing.

Comment: @pmr "the accepted types and the return types do not match." They could match if the mysterious struct I'm after will make them match before applying the composition.  As for practicality, I'm a math guy who likes to deal with mappings of functions, so I'm intrigued by how this could be put into code.

Comment: Are you sure that your `make_rotated_indices` example above works the way you want? Does `make_rotated_indices<5,2>` equal `pack_indices<2,1,0,4,3>`?

Comment: I ask because this fails: `static_assert(std::is_base_of<pack_indices<2,1,0,4,3>, C>::value, "");`

Comment: @0x499602D2. Yes. My rotation is defined to be to the left, not to the right. make_rotated_indices<5,2> is supposed to give pack_indices<2,3,4,0,1>. I tested it out already with various values.  But even if the rotation was not as I expected, I still need to know how to compose the two rotations.

Comment: std::cout << std::is_base_of<pack_indices<2,3,4,0,1>, make_rotated_indices<5,2>::type>::value; gives value true.  I do believe all my make_indices structs work correctly.  Just don't know how to compose them (and then also self-compose one of them multiple times).

Comment: So you want `compose<B, C, A>::type` to be `std::tuple<pack_indicies<...>, pack_indices<...>, pack_indices<...>>`?

Comment: And why does `make_rotated_indices` have a `type` instead of inheriting from `pack_indices` like the other two?

Comment: I want compose<B, C, A>::type to be pack_indices<1,0,4> (my opening post shows the transitions leading to it).  make_rotated_indices_helper, which is inherited from pack_indices, could be used instead of make_rotated_indices actually, but I just wanted to tidy it up by removing the 3rd template paramter.

Comment: I'm not sure how `compose<B,C,A>` translates to `pack_indices<1,0,4>`. I've got an example that turns it into a type list consisting of the base classes of `B`,`C`, and `A` like I showed in my other comment. Can you explain further what `compose` actually does?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55878/discussion-between-0x499602d2-and-prestokeys).

Answer (score 0):

One posible solution could be using simple recursion and the binary concatenation:

```
template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
struct concat;

template<std::size_t... Is , std::size_t... Js>
struct concat<sequence<Is...>,sequence<Js...>>
{
    using type = sequence<Is...,Js...>;
};

template<typename... Ss>
struct multi_concat;

template<typename HEAD , typename... TAIL>
struct multi_concat<HEAD,TAIL...>
{
    using type = typename concat<HEAD,typename multi_concat<TAIL...>::type>::type;
};

template<>
struct multi_concat<>
{
    using type = sequence<>;
};
```

Comment: But I don't see how 'concat<make_rotated_indices<10,2>, make_rotated_indices<10,4>>::type' would give the net effect make_rotated_indices<10,6>::type as it is expected to be. I think it is composition that I searching for after all, not concatenation (sorry I misunderstood what you guys meant by concatenation).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a start of what I'm trying to achieve.  It is not generalized because it is being carried out only for rotation as an illustration (and it is self-composition instead of general composition of arbitrarily many functions):

```
template <int N, std::size_t SHIFT, std::size_t... INDICES>
struct rotateAgain;

template <int N, std::size_t SHIFT, typename... TYPES>  // N is the number of times rotation by SHIFT is being done
void rotatePack (TYPES&&... types) {
    const typename make_rotated_indices<sizeof...(TYPES), SHIFT>::type indices;
    rotateAgain<N-1, SHIFT>()(indices, types...);
}

template <int N, std::size_t SHIFT, std::size_t... INDICES>
struct rotateAgain {
    template <typename... TYPES>
    void operator() (const pack_indices<INDICES...>&, const TYPES&... types) const {
        const typename make_rotated_indices<sizeof...(TYPES), SHIFT>::type indices;
        Pack::print (Pack::get<INDICES>(types...)...);
        rotatePack<N, SHIFT> (Pack::get<INDICES>(types...)...);
    }
};

template <std::size_t SHIFT, std::size_t... INDICES>
struct rotateAgain<0, SHIFT, INDICES...> {
    template <typename... TYPES>
    void operator() (const pack_indices<INDICES...>&, const TYPES&... types) const {
        std::cout << "End of recursion" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

There must be some way to generalize this from make_rotated_indices (which is being used above) to any of the make_indices types defined.